# Grunt - Unable to run serve: "Warning: Task "autoprefixer" not found"

Tags: gruntjs, npm, yeoman, bower

I'm following the tutorial on yeoman web page and now stuck at step 5: http://yeoman.io/codelab/preview-inbrowser.html

After the first time `grunt serve`, this error occured "Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt."

I realized that grunt hasn't been installed locally on my project then I run `sudo npm install grunt --save-dev`

Now I'm be able to run `grunt serve`, but it gave me a warning and ofcourse I'm still unable to start my server. Below is my screenshot:
[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and have also tried running `npm install` and `bower install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out the solution. For some who also encountered this, I made a mistake when use `sudo npm install --global yo bower grunt-cli`. I should have instead followed these steps: https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md

After that if you still get a " Warning: ENOENT, no such file or directory **/app/bower.json", check this:
https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep/issues/100